# Microsoft Dynamics NAV: Error Message Log

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, cal

I'm still new to using Dynamics NAV and I'm still a junior Dev so I have a few questions:

I need to be able to Log error messages in NAV as they happen, I have the following fields in a table:

1   Entry No.   Integer
2   Error Message   Integer
3   Object ID   Integer
4   Session ID  Integer
5   User ID         Integer
6   Object Name Text    250

It needs to log that information when an error occurs, I'm not really sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are trying to log errors in a specific object you are working on.

Typically, I use

```
   String := GETLASTERRORTEXT
```

in my custom code, when calling other Codeunits. This will give you the error description, which you can insert into your custom error log table.

Here is the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/getlasterrortext-function

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assistance, I have managed to getting it to work using the code you provided as well as the documentation

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it helped. Would you please mark the answer as correct, if it resolved your question?